# jQuery - How to hide a ul if the first li child is empty

Tags: jquery

I am using a UL, LI list to create some jQuery tabs in my application. I am using the tabs in a template page, some pages have content for the tabs and some don't.  On those page without content, the tab names still show up but the content for each tab will be empty.

I want to remove the ul tabs if my first li child is empty.  Below is my code. Basicaly, I want to hide ul#tabs if div#tab1 is empty. Any idea how to do this?  Thank you.

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>    
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1">
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal7" Text='<%# Eval("Overview") %>' runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal8" Text='<%# Eval("Agenda") %>' runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
if ($.trim($('#content div:first').html()).length == 0) {
    $('#tabs').hide();
}
```